# Cache not invalidating when new entry is created

Tags: cache

I realise this is probably a duplicate of the other questions just like it but I thought I'd raise it here before filing a bug with P&T.

Basically, when a new entry is added to a section, the template cache isn't invalidating. Here is the template in question, is there anything in the code that would cause this?

```
    {% extends "_layouts/two-col" %}

    {% block main %}

        {% cache unless not craft.config.cache %}

        {{entry.body}} 

        {% set cutoffDate = now|date_modify('- ' ~ '1' ~ ' days') %}
        {% set events = craft.entries.section('whatsOn').order('dateStart') %}

        {% set eventIds = [] %}
        {% for event in events if (event.dateEnd ? event.dateEnd : event.dateStart) >= cutoffDate %}
          {% set eventIds = eventIds|merge([event.id]) %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% set allEvents = craft.entries.id(eventIds).fixedOrder('true') %}

        {% paginate allEvents.limit(12) as events %}

        <ul class="list list--articles">

            {% for event in events %}

                <li class="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">

                    <header class="item__header">

                        <div class="item__meta">

                            <time itemprop="startDate" content="{{event.dateStart}}" datetime="{{event.dateStart}}">{{event.dateStart|date("jS F Y")}}</time>

                            {% if event.dateEnd|length %}
                                — <time itemprop="endDate" content="{{event.dateStart}}" datetime="{{event.dateStart}}">{{event.dateEnd|date("jS F Y")}}</time>
                            {% endif %}

                        </div>

                        <h3 class="item__title h4" itemprop="name"><a href="{{ event.url }}" class="">{{ event.title }}</a></h3>

                        <div class="item__type">
                            <span class="tag tag--{{event.eventType|slugify}}">{{event.eventType}}</span>
                            <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"> {{event.location}}</span>
                        </div>

                    </header>

                    <div class="item__description">
                        <a href="{{ event.url }}">Find out more</a>
                    </div>

                </li>

            {% endfor %}

        </ul>


        {% if paginate.totalPages > 1 %}

            <nav class="nav nav--pagination">

                <ul class="nav__list">

                {# <a href="{{ paginate.firstUrl }}">First Page</a> #}
            {# {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %} #}

            {% for page, url in paginate.getPrevUrls(5) %}
              <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="{{ url }}" class="nav__link">{{ page }}</a>
              </li>
            {% endfor %}

            <li class="nav__item nav__item--active"><span class="nav__link">{{ paginate.currentPage }}</span></li>

            {% for page, url in paginate.getNextUrls(5) %}
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="{{ url }}" class="nav__link">{{ page }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}

           {#  {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
            <a href="{{ paginate.lastUrl }}">Last Page</a> #}

                </ul>

            </nav>

        {% endif %}

        {% endpaginate %}

        {% endcache %}  

    {% endblock %}

    {% block sidebar %}

        {% include '_partials/newsletter-signup' with { grid:'false' } %}

        {% include '_partials/social' %}

    {% endblock %}
```

If this all looks normal, I guess it is a bug with Craft?

Comment: Any updates on this issue, harmish?

Comment: Kind of. P&T looked in to it but were unable to re-produce the problem reliably so it's not something that's going to be fixed in any sort of time-frame, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Looks like this is doomed to linger unless the problem magically fixes itself. I've had a similar issue with rather meaty sub-templates, but that doesn't seem relevant here. Would you mind adding your Craft version and clarifying what environment(s) are pertinent here, if only for posterity?

Comment: It appears this was fixed in a recent Craft update :)

Comment: I'm actually still experiencing problems with this so not sure if it was indeed fixed.

Comment: Can everyone confirm that this happens when using the `{% cache %}` tag in combination with the `{% paginate %}` tag and when creating a new entry?